# How to suppress D9025 warning in Microsoft C++ build tools

Tags: c++, visual-studio, msbuild, suppress-warnings

I am compiling a library with Microsoft C++ compiler and build tools.  My build environment sets the compile flag /GL, but for a specific library I need to turn that flag off.  I can do so with /GL-, but I get a warning D9025, which simply tells me I am overriding the previous setting.
I want to suppress this warning.  But the command line option /wd only forks for Cxxx errors and warnings, not Dxxx warnings.  How do I suppress the D9025 warning?

Comment: Remove the conflicting flag from your build settings for the library.

Comment: @dans3itz Unfortunately, I can’t. Damn `node-gyp`.

Answer (score 7):

You cannot suppress D9025, you have to fix that. [Command-line warning D9025](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8k3f51f1.aspx) means you have conflicting options on cl.exe command line. In your case you have something like this:

```
cl ... /GL ... /GL- ...
```

Compiler actually uses the option that is specified last on the command line, but that command line is very confusing.

In your .vcxproj file make sure you have set correct option for WholeProgramOptimization property. Your configuration section might look like this:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|x64'" Label="Configuration">
  ...
  <WholeProgramOptimization>false</WholeProgramOptimization>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: I tried changing my options to use dashes instead of slashes (to try and minimize the amount of MSVC-specific code), and the D9025 warning only shows up when using dashes. I don't think there's actually conflicting arguments. MSVC says it supports dashes, so I think this is a bug and a false warning that I'd like to silence.

Comment: I think I have a legitimate desire to override the option for the one peculiar module in my makefile, so I don't consider I need to fix something wrong about my build but rather that I need to implement a workaround for MSC.  Thank you for the answer; have a vote.

Answer (score 2):

This is a little old, but in case others experience this and land here...

It's hard to say exactly what is going on for this user, but in Visual Studio this issue can arise in the following instance:

Right click on:

- The offending project => properties
- Configuration Properties => C/C++ => Command Line

By example:

- If you look at the "All Options", there might be this option: /MT
- In the box at the bottom "Additional Options", it might have: /MD

These are in conflict - hence the warning.

To fix it, delete the /MD in Additional Options.

Then browse to: Configuration Properties => C/C++ => Code Generation.

Set the Runtime Library to: /MD

Again, this is only one scenario of how this can occur, but something similar might be occurring if the user is using a makefile (setting the RuntimeLibrary to one value, then using AdditionOptions to set it to something contentious)

BTW, it's just a warning, it ends up using the value specified in AddtionOptions.